# MySQL query cache or other bug (Codeigniter + MySQL)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am having a very odd issue that I cannot figure out. The query below was returning `0`, then I copied the database to another server and it returned `36`. Then all of a sudden on production it started working again. When I manually ran the query it would return `36` but in CodeIgniter it would be `0` sometimes but now it is `36`.

```
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->where('system_item',0);
$this->db->where('category_id',228);

// Should return 36; was returning 0; data didn't change
$items_count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Comment: Maybe it needs to specify what you are actually selecting, try to add `$this->db->select('*');` or any column that you want to count on..

Comment: Count_all_results adds count(*) as num_rows